# What are these accelerating flare countermeasures called?

Tags: military, fa-18

There seems to be a type of flare countermeasure, that not only gets ejected from the flare dispenser, but also gets accelerated in the direction of the plane. So fare I´ve only noticed it on super and legacy Hornets. 
My question is, whether anybody knows the actual name for those kinds of flares, and if there is any kind of information on how they work.

[Video of legacy Hornet dispensing a normal and an accelerating flare](https://youtu.be/ONA0Ahm4oOM?t=287)

On the left Hornet you can see one of the two flares accelerating forward in a spiral after it is out of the dispenser.

[Video of super Hornet dispensing a normal and an accelerating flare](https://youtu.be/02f7b9_Tlk8?t=218)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are generally called "propelled flares", or sometimes "aerodynamic propelled flares". Some antiaircraft systems are able to distinguish between a normal flare and the aircraft, as the flare is not travelling along the expected path of the aircraft. Aerodynamic flares were first developed to allow the flare to continue along the path, but as antiaircraft systems developed further, they added a method of propulsion (which uses the same fuel source as the flare itself), to ensure that the flare continued alongside the aircraft, slightly angled away, at a similar speed. This does a better job of confusing these aircraft systems, but it's a fairly "niche" type of flare that is meant to combat conical scanning.

I believe the ARM-031, MJU-47/B, and MJU-71/B are all forms of propelled flares.